# It's related to ROC curve

Tags: python-3.x

I have no problem in plotting the ROC curve and it also gets plotted as per my requirement, but the problem I am facing is in (ylim axes) it starts from 0.1 to 1.05, and it plots only even numbers (0.0 0.2 0.4...1.05), but I want to extend the ylim axes (for eg. 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3...1.05). I want a code which includes both even and odd number while plotting ROC curve.

I searched in matplotlib but I didn't find anything related to my problem.

[image]

```
lw = 2
plt.figure()
plt.plot(fpr11, tpr11, 'o-', ms=2, label='ROC_curve_APOE(AUC11 = %0.4f)' 
% roc_auc11, color='deeppink', linestyle=':', linewidth=2)
plt.plot(fpr51, tpr51, 'o-', ms=2, label='ROC_curve_Combined AUC5 = 
%0.4f)' % roc_auc51, color='cornflowerblue', linestyle=':', linewidth=2)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', lw=lw, linestyle='--')
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.ylim([0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('1-Specificity(False Positive Rate)')
plt.ylabel('Sensitivity(True Positive Rate)')
# plt.title('ROC curve for MCIc vs MCIs')
plt.title('ROC curve for AD vs NC')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
# plt.savefig('roc_auc.png')
plt.close()
```

My expected output must be the same as over here https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/#roc_curve_for_binary_svm
You can see in this figure that ylim has plotted every point from (0.0 0.1 ....up to 1).
Please help me solve it.

Comment: welcome on SO, I'm not familiar with plotting, but if you revise your question, the more answers you will get. Please look at this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.
A better question would be : "How to plot every point with `library`" (change library to what you use)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, from the next time I will follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you can set steps in `ylim/xlim` but you can use `xticks/yticks` instead

```py
def frange(x, y, jump):
    while x < y:
        yield x
        x += jump
    yield y
plt.yticks(list(frange(0, 1.05, 0.1)))
```

How you choose to replace the `frange` is up to you, but you can also do something like

```py
plt.yticks([0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4,....,1.0, 1.05])
```

Comment: Thanks for that, for me (plt.yticks) worked.
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 1.05, step=0.1))

Comment: yes you could use numpy as well of course, or any other method, I just used the simplest one with the least of requirements